# vue directive bind hook is not firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple vue directive to implement the material design ripple effect. For some reason, it is being totally ignored, not even the console statement is triggering and I can't figure out why. It must be pretty basic, because I can't event get something like this to work

```js
Vue.directive('ripple', {
  bind: function(el) {
    console.log('WHY ARENT YOU WORKING')
    console.log(el)
  },
})

//App.vue
<template>
  <div ripple>test</div>
</template>
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-water-tgyk1?file=/src/main.js:88-208)

Comment: try `<div v-ripple>test</div>`

Comment: Thank you! I was banging my head against the desk for hours trying to work this one out

Comment: Under [directive hook arguments](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments) `binding.name` reads: "*The name of the directive, without the* `v-` *prefix.*". Arguably, this convention should be advertised better.